# Byebug fully supports Windows or not?

Tags: ruby, windows, byebug

My environment is macOS and I don't have Windows environment. I am writing a blog post about Byebug and I want to know if it fully supports Windows or not. Here is information I got:

Might not work?

- Rails 5 adds `platform: :mri` option to byebug gem. ([see here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/23920))
- And [this document](http://bundler.io/v1.13/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS) says mri does not include Windows.
- I heard some people said that some commands (e.g.`restart`) did not work in their Windows PC.
- So Byebug does not support Windows?

Might work?

- CI tests are passing against Windows environment.([see here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/build/job/5jxyjm4kniqv6ji0))
- And I cannot find any limitation on Windows environment in [Byebug's README](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug).
- So Byebug supports Windows?

I am not sure which idea is right. Does anyone know about it?

### UPDATE

@deivid says Byebug supports Windows. Then, what is the valid platform option for Gemfile?

`:platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]` or `:platforms => [:mri, :mswin]`?

Here are the options exctracted from [this page](http://bundler.io/v1.13/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS).

- ruby => C Ruby (MRI) or Rubinius, but NOT Windows
- mri => Same as ruby, but not Rubinius
- rbx => Same as ruby, but only Rubinius (not MRI)
- jruby => JRuby
- mswin => Windows
- mingw => Windows 32 bit 'mingw32' platform (aka RubyInstaller)
- x64_mingw => Windows 64 bit 'mingw32' platform (aka RubyInstaller x64)

In [this comment](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2910#issuecomment-36415395):

> mswin and mingw are completely different things.

And mswin seems these packages:

https://www.artonx.org/data/asr/

And Byebug CI is running against mingw and x64_mingw only, so I guess it should be `:platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]`, correct?

Comment: It is working for me with Ruby 2.5 on Windows. I installed Msys2 tool chain to build the native extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `byebug` support Windows.

> Rails 5 adds platform: :mri option to byebug gem. (see here)

Windows platforms were probably overlooked when that patch was added.

> And this document says mri does not include Windows.

That's right.

> I heard some people said that some commands (e.g.restart) did not work in their Windows PC.

Those people should report those issues to the project.

> CI tests are passing against Windows environment.(see here)

Thtat's right, the best indicator of support ;)

> And I cannot find any limitation on Windows environment in Byebug's README.

Another good indicator :)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Then what is the valid option for Gemfile? (I updated my question.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know know whether `byebug` works or not in the `mswin` platform. I guess it's a matter of trying...

Comment: I see. Then I think mswin should not be included because it has no tests.

Answer (score 5):

`gem 'byebug', platform: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]`

`byebug` is now working on my windows rails app. This is not obvious from the selected answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that it works... but it was rubbish so I gave up. Couldn't use bash history, anything I would normally do on Linux usually would crash byebug on Windows. Arrow keys etc. It was easier to learn Vagrant and spin up a VM.